# Is there a way to identify which WP Cron event/hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron

My woocommerce site is having some performance issue and I am suspecting there are some WP Cron job causing it each time my website is accessed. I would like to identify the offending WP Cron event or hook.

Is there a way to identify based on the log below:

###.###.###.### - - [04/Aug/2022:06:59:10 +0800] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1659567550.8263061046600341796875 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://website.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1659567550.8263061046600341796875" "WordPress/5.8.4; https://website.com"

I have WP Crontrol installed but can't figure which WP Cron hook does the log refer to. Hope to get some guidance from you all. Thank you.